# Can't input file name when running method in while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

Having a bit of trouble getting one of my methods to properly run when using it in a while loop. Basically I need to specify a file to read from in order to output its contents, which works fine when not in the loop. But once I try calling it from within the loop, it runs it without letting me input anything, which naturally gives me a "FileNotFoundException" error. The method in question is getParameters. Here's my code so far:

```
public class Tile {

private static String fileName = null;
private static int imageHeight =0;
private static int imageWidth=0;
public static int MAXSIDE = 100;
private static String[][] buffer = new String[MAXSIDE][MAXSIDE];
public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
    boolean a = askPermission();
    while(a = true){
        getParameters();
        getImage();
        printImage();
        a = askPermission();
    }
    System.out.println("No more? All done then!");
}

public static boolean askPermission(){
    System.out.println("Would you like to tile an image? Enter either y or n ------> ");
    String a = scan.next();
    if(a == "y"){

        return true;
    }
    else{

        return false;
    }

}

static void getParameters() 
{
    System.out.println("Please type the name of the file you would like to tile: ");
    fileName = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Getting image...");
}

public  static void getImage() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    imageHeight = input.nextInt();
    imageWidth = input.nextInt();
    input.useDelimiter("(?<=.)");
    for(int i=0; i<imageHeight;i++){

        for(int j=0; j<imageWidth; j++){
            buffer[i][j] = input.next();
        }   
    }
    input.close();

}

public  static void printImage()
{
    for(int i=0; i<imageHeight;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<imageWidth; j++){
            System.out.print(buffer[i][j]);
        }

    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

Comment: 1. Use `scan.nextLine()` for both your Scanner calls and 2. Never compare Strings with `==`. Use `equals(...)`.

Comment: `while(a = true)` should be `while(a)` or `while(a == true)`

Comment: Understand that `==` tests for *reference* equality which is not what you're interested while the equals method tests for functional equality -- do the two Strings hold the same chars in the same order -- and that's what matters. So instead of `if(a == "y"){`, do `if ("y".equalsIgnoreCase(a)) {` or `if ("y".equals(a)) {`

Comment: That did the trick! Changed the calls to nextLine, and its working fine now! Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :)

```
private static String fileName = null;
private static int imageHeight = 0;
private static int imageWidth = 0;
public static int MAXSIDE = 100;
private static String[][] buffer = new String[MAXSIDE][MAXSIDE];
public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
    boolean a = askPermission();
    while (a == true) {
        getParameters();
        getImage();
        printImage();
        a = askPermission();
    }
    System.out.println("No more? All done then!");
}

public static boolean askPermission() {
    System.out.println("Would you like to tile an image? Enter either y or n ------> ");
    String a = scan.next();
    if ("y".equals(a)) {

        return true;
    } else {

        return false;
    }

}

static void getParameters() {
    System.out.println("Please type the name of the file you would like to tile: ");
    fileName = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Getting image...");
}

public static void getImage() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    imageHeight = input.nextInt();
    imageWidth = input.nextInt();
    input.useDelimiter("(?<=.)");
    for (int i = 0; i < imageHeight; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < imageWidth; j++) {
            buffer[i][j] = input.next();
        }
    }
    input.close();

}

public static void printImage() {
    for (int i = 0; i < imageHeight; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < imageWidth; j++) {
            System.out.print(buffer[i][j]);
        }

    }
    System.out.println(); 
}
```